# Tensorflow giving a ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

I'm trying to implement a loss function that increases loss as the model ranks images from worst to best, to do this I've come up with an algorithm that sorts the predicted score array according to the true scores of the image batch, then starting from the largest predicted score, check how far away it is from the first position in the array and give it a loss based on that, for the second largest we will see how far away it is from the 2nd array position and give it a loss based on that

To do this, I'm using tf.nn.top_k and other functions that I looked up to all be differentiable to my knowledge, but I still get the No gradients provided error

Can someone please tell me what part am I doing wrong?

Please note that the global `sub_tensor` was a workaround (to replace `correct_indices`) I was doing to avoid using a range which I know is non-differentiable, an array from outside the function that is fixed to be a range of the length of the batch [0-32]. This still didn't work

```
sub_tensor = constant(np.array([np.arange(32)],dtype='int32'))

def get_ranking_loss(y_true,y_pred):
    global sub_tensor
    _, y_true_ind_k = tf.nn.top_k(y_true, y_true.shape[1])

    sorted_y_pred = tf.gather(y_pred,y_true_ind_k)
        
    _, y_pred_ind_k = tf.nn.top_k(sorted_y_pred, sorted_y_pred.shape[1])

    # correct_indices = tf.range(0,sorted_y_pred.shape[1])
    subtracted = tf.math.subtract(y_pred_ind_k,sub_tensor)
    absolute = tf.abs(subtracted)
    absolute = tf.cast(absolute, float64)
    return tf.reduce_sum(absolute)
```

I tried to change almost all functions to be tf functions only, but no luck

Comment: What is `cast`? Is it `tf.cast()`? If yes, it is not differentiable.

Comment: Yes, it is `tf.cast`, forgot to include that line of code, I'll try to remove it

Comment: No luck, still causes the same error unfortunately. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Ranking is not differentiable, just like any discrete function. For `top_k`, the first result (the top k values) _is_ differentiable, but the indices (which is what you are using) aren't. It's just like `max` is differentiable, but `argmax` isn't.